# Kotlin - extract list of parent objects of items in Collection

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way in Kotlin to extract list of parent objects of items in Collection. 
For instance if we have mutableMaps:

```
val AllPersons = mutableMapOf<Long,Person>() 
val ClassAttendants = mutableMapOf<Long,Person>()
```

where Person is:

```
data class Person( PID : Long
    Name: String
    Surname: String
    Father: Person?)
```

Is there a way to select all (distinct) grandfathers from class attendants?

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: To tell you the truth I dont have a clue where to begin. I'm stuck because I've been using LINQ for a long time and I can't find anything similar here. It's like I miss SELECT keyword :) I tried with filtering (ClassAttendants.Filter) but it got me nowhere

Answer (score 2):

As I'm not one for giving complete solutions, I'll give you a bunch of building blocks that should probably be helpful.

1. We can get the parent for a given element with `somePerson.father`.
2. We can apply a function over all value elements in a map like this:

   ```
   myMap.values.map { value -> someFunction(value) }
   ```
3. We can filter out `null` values like this:

   ```
   myCollection.filterNotNull()
   ```
4. A `Set` will automatically "discard" duplicate elements.  An alternative is something like this:

   ```
   myCollection.distinct()
   ```

I'd strongly recommend going through the [Kotlin Koans](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/koans.html).  In particular, the "Collections" section touches on applying quasi-functional techniques to manipulate collections.

Comment: Thanks, mapping seems promising.